# Running dialog tool inside shell function in makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, dialog

When trying to run dialog program inside some script which is called by

```
my_var := $(shell script.sh)
```

in my Makefile I can't see a dialog window, the screen just hangs. Running script in usual way (like ./script.sh) works, but I want to get output of the script so this way isn't what I'm looking for. How do I make it appear?

```
#script.sh
dialog --checklist ...
```

Likely, the problem is that $shell function doesn't show stdout of process it runs. Is there a way to force stdout for parent process?

Comment: If `./script` works from a terminal, and if your `Makefile` is located in the same directory, it is likely you're missing the `./` in the `shell` command of the Makefile.